# Help with a book, title something like Shattered or Fractured?

Tags: story-identification, books

There was a book published in the last five years, listed in adult sci-fi/fantasy I'm pretty sure with a cover design that looked like shattered glass, and the title might be like 'fractured' or 'shattered'.

I think it was about a woman who had been betrayed somehow by her sister, maybe turned in to the authorities, maybe for murder, she might have been sent to jail.

It has a sequel. I think the main character has violent impulses, and some kind of psychic-ish abilities.

There might be a mystery involved about what the main character actually did or didn't do, and they might have
I believe the book is about the relationship between the two sisters, and I think the setting is contemporary, or at least not in the distant past.

The protagonist's memory or perceptions of reality might have been altered or be distorted, but, again, I'm not sure.

Sorry for all the vagueness, don't remember solid details. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Judging from the description, this might be Fracture, book 2 of the Blood and Roses series.

[image]

Judging from your description:

1. Cover with shattered glass: check;
2. Title similar to Fractured or Shattered: check;
3. books about sisters: check;
4. One of the sisters has disappeared: check;
5. Published in the last five years: check.

Goodreads link: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21417329-fracture

Comment: It's also available on Kindle Unlimited. Which is nice.

Answer (score 6):

Not an exact match for your question, but [Vicious](https://veschwab.wordpress.com/books-at-a-glance/vicious/), by V.E. Schwab, has a number of similarities:

- Two sisters are involved with the protagonists
- One sister betrayed the other
- One sister has psychic abilities that enable her to control people
- Setting is contemporary
- Book was released in 2013

[image: Cover art of Vicious]

From the author's [site](https://veschwab.wordpress.com/books-at-a-glance/vicious/):

> A masterful, twisted tale of ambition, jealousy, betrayal, and
>   superpowers, set in a near-future world.

Comment: I've read Vicious, it's not that, thanks for your time though!

Answer (score 3):

### [Slated Trilogy](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Slated-Trilogy-Collection-Fractured-Shattered/dp/B00KM84X9E/)

From your description, it could be these books. I haven't read them, but they appear to check enough boxes to at least be mentioned.

- the female protagonist was arrested for some unknown crime
- the protagonists memories were reset/altered
- the names OP suggested matches two of the three books exactly (Shattered and Fractured)
- the books were published recently
- the covers off all the books contain different sorts of broken material (like glass or porcelain).